# Kan extensions and restriction

Tags: ct.category-theory, kan-extension

Suppose $A \to B$ be a fully faithful (codense if it helps, i.e. every object in $B$ is the small limit of a diagram in A) embedding of categories. Let $b$ be an object of $B$, $Hom_B(b,-)$ defines (restrict to) a functor $A \to Set$ which is denoted by $Hom_B(b,-)|_A$ . When does the left or right Kan extension of $Hom_B(b,-)|_A$ along $A \to B$ isomorphic to $Hom_B(b,-)$ ?

Comment: If $A$ is dense and $b$ is in $A$, then the left Kan extension of the restriction recovers the original hom functor. This is essentially tautological, by the definition of density. Slightly less trivial example: if $b$ is a retract of an object in $A$ then it has the same property.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thx for your comment. What if b is not in A? and what about the right Kan extension? BTW I should probably say codense instead of dense, i.e. every object in $B$ is a small limit of a diagram in $A$.

Comment: Covariant hom functors preserve all limits (in the strongest possible sense) so if $A$ is codense in $B$ then the right Kan extension of the restriction of any hom functor will recover the original hom functor.

Comment: This seems true to me but it's not clear to me how to prove this rigorously. Should I use for example the limit formula to prove this?

Comment: Yes. The same limit diagram is used in both the definition of codensity and in the definition of pointwise right Kan extension. (No surprise, because codensity is really talking about a certain pointwise right Kan extension.)

Comment: @ZhenLin right, that makes sense. I'm wondering if the same holds for enriched categories and 2 categories? It seems that the limit formula for pointwise right Kan extension in the 2-categorical setting is less commonly documented.

Comment: There is a limit formula for enriched categories too: $\mathcal{C} (c, \operatorname{Ran}_F G (b)) \cong [\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{V}](\mathcal{B} (b, F), \mathcal{C} (c, G))$, hence $\operatorname{Ran}_F G (b)$ is a weighted limit in $\mathcal{B}$ of a diagram of shape $\mathcal{A}$.